# replace styles.less with styles.css via git post-receive

Tags: html, git, deployment, less, git-post-receive

I have a local development web with an index.html which is using:

```
<!-- LESS -->
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="css/styles.less" />
<script src="js/lib/less-1.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When I am ready editing I commit/push to my development server and the git post-receive hook runs my build.sh and builds my css / requireJS / smartsprites app.

How can I replace the above code in my static HTML file with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
```

without switching to server-side scripting (PHP/etc) or on the fly node.js css rendering.

In my build.sh script? With regexp? How? An example would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `sed`:

```
sed -i -e 's/styles\.less/styles\.css/g' index.html
```

I haven't used `git-post-receive` (I didn't even know it existed! thanks :P), but you could just shove it into your `build.sh` file or whatever file runs when you push your files to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the git hook thing. I always manually change stuff every time I push my code, so this should make it *much* easier to manage.